# Unable to import isotope plugin---"$(container).isotope is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, import, jquery-isotope

I've had zero luck with getting the [Metafizzy Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html) plugin working. The Network tab shows that it's not coming through.

I installed `isotope-layout` and required it in my `main-file.js`, but the code fails to recognize `$(container).isotope`.

[image]

The part that's blacked out is the actual name of `main-file.js`.

I'm also working with webpack and have wondered if it's part of the problem, but I can't say for sure.

---

**index.js:**

```
// css imports here

import "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";

import mainfile from "./SiteAssets/scripts/main-file.js";
```

**main-file.js:**

```
import axios from "axios";
import "@babel/polyfill/dist/polyfill.js";

var isotope = require('isotope-layout'); // Seeing "'isotope' is declared but its value is never read

// var isotope = require('imports-loader?$=jquery!isotope-layout/dist/isotope.pkgd');

// import isotope from "isotope-layout";

let myClass,
    names,
    _token;

export default class {
    constructor() {
        myClass = this;
        myClass.setTokenVar();
        // a few irrelevant things here

        myClass.loadSpecFilter();

    }

     loadSpecFilter() {
        var $grid = $('.keyContactDiv').isotope({
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            // layoutMode: 'fitRows',
            getSortData: {
                name: '.spec-name'
            }
        })

        $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
            var sortByValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-by');
            $grid.isotope({ sortBy: sortByValue });
        });

        $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
            var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
            $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
                $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
                $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
            });
        });
     }

}
```

**my-html.html:**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="filters">
        <div class="btn-group button-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info filter-item" data-filter="*">Show All</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info filter-item" data-sort-by="spec-name">A-Z</button>
            <!-- some other buttons here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Finally, I used JS and jQuery to create the div elements that I want to filter. Here's a screencap:

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvioM.png)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
npm install jquery
npm install jquery-bridget

import $ from 'jquery';
import jQueryBridget from 'jquery-bridget';
import Isotope from 'isotope-layout';

// make Isotope a jQuery plugin
jQueryBridget( 'isotope', Isotope, $ );
// now you can use $().isotope()
$('.grid').isotope({
  // options...
});
```

OR

```
import $ from "jquery";
import Isotope from "isotope-layout";

var grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
var iso = new Isotope( grid, {
          itemSelector: ".all",
          percentPosition: true,
          masonry: {
            columnWidth: ".all"
          }
});
$('.filters ul li').click(function() { // To filter your isotope.
    var data = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    iso.arrange({
       filter: data // All grid items
    });
});
```